# Cant retrieve data correctly from realm

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to implement a generic realm wrapper. So, i can pass an object with its class to either add/update or get. I am using the realm browser to confirm that i am saving the data correctly, but when i perform a getAll query, i receive an array with the correct amount with the correct data structure but all the fields are in default values or null.
Here is my code :

Add RealmModel: (UserRealmModel)

```
@Override
public void putAll(Collection<RealmObject> realmModels) {
    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    mRealm.beginTransaction();
    mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(realmModels);
    mRealm.commitTransaction();
}
```

GetAllRealmModels: (UserRealmModel)

```
@Override
public RealmResults getAll(Class clazz) {
    return Realm.getDefaultInstance().allObjects(clazz);
}
```

I also tried:

```
@Override
public RealmResults getAll(Class clazz) {
    return Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(clazz).findAll();
}
```

clazz = UserRealmModel.class

Output:

[image: GetAll Output in debugger]

But whats interesting that in the debug view as shown in the screenshot, the toString method shows the correct data!

Help please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr Zeyad, 
I went through Realm documentation for you. They have a well written document with an eample for your question.

They say,

**Adding a watch in Android Studio on a RealmObject will display values of the fields. Unfortunately these values are wrong because the field values are not used. Realm creates a proxy object behind the scenes and overrides the getters and setters in order to access the persisted data in the Realm. Adding a watch for any of the accessors will yield correct values**.

[image: See the Image]

In the image above the debugger has stopped on line 113. There are three watch values, the person variable and the person.getName() and person.getAge() accessors. The code from lines 107 to 111 alters the person instance by changing the name and age. These values are then persisted in a transaction. On line 113, where the debugger is currently paused, the person watch instance is reporting on field values and they are incorrect. The watch values that use the accessor for person.getName() and person.getAge() report values that are correct.

Please note, the .toString() method will output the correct values but the watch panel will not (when watching a variable which is a RealmObject).

[Read More Here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#testing-and-debugging)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. It was a bit confusing because i was casting the results from realm objects to my view model, so i was losing all the data